# Spring boot 2.6 incompatible with Cloud Sleuth 3.1.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm using Spring Boot 2.6 and Spring Cloud Sleuth 3.1.4
Whenever I run the app I'm getting this:

```
Your project setup is incompatible with our requirements due to following reasons:

- Spring Boot [2.6.0] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train


Action:

Consider applying the following actions:

- Change Spring Boot version to one of the following versions [2.4.x, 2.5.x] .
You can find the latest Spring Boot versions here [https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn]. 
If you want to learn more about the Spring Cloud Release train compatibility, you can visit this page [https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#overview] and check the [Release Trains] section.
If you want to disable this check, just set the property [spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false]
```

According to release train 2021.0.x should be compatible with Spring boot 2.6 and sleuth 3.1.4 is a part of it.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: As you mentioned, this version of Spring Cloud Sleuth should work. Maybe there's a conflicting dependency somewhere that causes a wrong version to be imported. Can you show us your `pom.xml` (preferably a minimal version only including the dependencies necessary to reproduce the problem).

Answer (score 0):

In the compatibility matrix, as listed here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud, under '**Release Train**' section, this should work.
But, I would recommend you to lower the spring cloud version to 3.1.3 to begin with. If you still get the same error, try with version 3.1.0. as in my project I had no problems using `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` 3.1.0 with Spring Boot 2.6.x.

Best regards,
Filip

**EDIT:** With spring sleuth 3.1.4 you should use `spring-cloud-dependencies` of version 2021.0.4. Maybe here you got the problem.